# How can i alter my arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, smack, alter

i search more about my problem, but know i thought about it and i need to alter the arraylist. I saw about this fuctions Collections.swap(list,x,y), and this is cool, but only if i like to change one element for other. So i need a method that change the first places and put my users online with this condition:

```
if(userpresence.getmode()==null&&userpresence.isAvailable()){
listItem.add(new contacts(name,user,icon))
}
if(userpresence.getmode()==null&&!userpresence.isAvailable()){
    listItem.add(new contacts(name,user,icon))
}
```

in this part i show the list sort aphabetically:

```
    Collections.sort(listItem);

//I think the method about I tell you is in this part 

    ObservableList<Contacts> ob=FXCollections.observableArrayList(listItem);
    listview.setitems(ob);
```

and the idea is something like this:

```
user online
user online
user online
user online
user offline
user offline
user offline
user offline
user offline
```

but in this case only i show in this way:

```
user offline
user offline
user offline
user offline
user offline
user online
user offline
user offline
user offline
user online
user offline
user offline
user offline
user online
user offline
user offline
user offline
user online
user offline
user offline
user offline
user online
user offline
user offline
user offline
user offline
user online
user offline
user offline
```

because I try to do the comparasing and the effect about this not shown.
this is my method comparator:

```
public static Comparator<Contacts> contactsComparator=new Comparator<Contacts>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Contacts c1, Contacts c2) {
        String ContactName1=c1.getName().toUpperCase();
        String ContactName2=c2.getName().toUpperCase();


        return ContactName1.compareTo(ContactName2);
    }
};
```

and in the collections.sort i put this (arraylist,contacts.contactsComparator)

Comment: Is your question about how to sort an arraylist?  It is not clear what you are asking.  The static `sort()` method will sort a list that has a *natural ordering*.  The natural ordering is established by having your class (in this case "contacts") implement the Comparable interface.

Comment: not exactly because i already have my list order now i need to put the method swap

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: i try to do a list of contacts similar to the skype or psi or facebook

Comment: So you want the users who are online to show up first in the list. And that means the list is NOT in the order you want.

Comment: will I need to put the sorted list the fact is that I have to do it twice because the first is to make this neat online and the other is for offline

Comment: Please re-edit your question to make the problem that you wish to solve more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: thanks i can do that sorry for not answer

Answer (score 4):

Collections.sort(list) only works if your objects implement the interface *java.lang.Comparable*. Otherwise you need to implement and pass a *java.util.Comparator* to the sort method as well. Either is needed to define the sort order for your objects.

Comment: i implement the collections.sort(arraylist), and its good, i need to put an other method to change the positions and i think the good way is with the method swap, but i have a lot of positions and i need to put the users online in the top of my list

Comment: I meant the Contacts class. Does it implement the Comparable interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)? If you are not sure what I mean, please post its code. And no, you don't need to manually swap elements in your list. Collections.sort() does that if used correctly.